# returns null on short GraphQL query

Tags: graphql, api-platform.com

I've set up a new API-Platform instance and its GraphQL endpoint behaves strangely.

This query **does not work**:

```
query { Asset { id, name }}
```

It will return me:

```
{
  "data": {
    "Asset": null
  }
}
```

Which is wrong, I do have data.

**This query works**:

```
{
  Assets {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get the correct data. In all online examples of GraphQL, the first syntax is used. So I assume that it is the correct syntax.

The similar issue exists for mutations.

What am I doing wrong? How to get the short query form to work?

Comment: Do you have permissions to read from database when doing request? Don't you need some kind if token?

Comment: Can you post your `resolver`?

Comment: @parohy permissions are not a problem. And as I said, just writing the query in a different way gives me results.

Comment: @novaline - I didn't write any custom resolvers. I'm using plain API Platform. I'm under the assumption that should be enough?

Comment: @Tom Does it give any error in the console?

Comment: No, I don't see errors. Neither in GraphQL playground nor in Graphiql.

Comment: And do the query has some arguments like id for example? not sure how you can resolve otherwise what asset to obtain. I suggest to check if there is the argument id and use some node id from Assets query to see if it is working.

Comment: The query is exactly as I posted above. I don't want to retrieve a specific asset, I want to retrieve them all.

Comment: You first query queries `Asset`, your second query looks for `Assets` (Plural!). They seem to be different queries with different return types. It would be untypical to return `id` and `name` as well as `edges`.

Comment: I don't understand GraphQL completely, but as I wrote, the first query is modelled after pretty much every example I can find, and they use singular form as well. Is API-Platform different from other GraphQL implementations? That wouldn't make sense, would it?

Comment: In `/graphiql` you can browse documentation, defined types, queries - you'll find singular and plural versions (and required parameters) made magically from/for each entity definitions. It even takes care about proper plural naming. API Platform does much more behind scene and of course taking some assumptions/style - sometimes it can be  recognized as a bit `different`.

Comment: So I understand the ability to do the first type of query is not a GraphQL feature, but a feature of (most) implementations? Graphcool, Apollo, etc. ?

Comment: It's type/schema based and it's rather lack of future 'array being countable and paginable'. Looking at types `Assets` isn't simply `array of Asset` but `edges:[AssetEdges]` (plus counter and pageinfo). API-P does it for you for free ;)

Answer (score 0):

The first query requires an id as it is singular, so something like this:

```
query {
    Asset(id: "/api/assets/1") {
        id
        name
    }
}
```

You can get it to work with plural:

```
query {
    Assets {
        id
        name
    }
}
```

But for that you need to disable pagination

```
# api/config/packages/api_platform.yaml
api_platform:
    collection:
        pagination:
            enabled: false
```